# How to find all documents which their array field contains only two specific values

Tags: java, mongodb

I did this but it returns all the documents which their authors field contains the two specific values and other values.

```
Document authors = new Document("authors","firstValue")
    .append("authors", "secondValue");

    MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find(authors).iterator();

    try {
        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            Document doc = cursor.next();
            System.out.println(doc.get("title")+ " " + doc.get("authors"));
        }
    } 
    finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
    client.close();
```

I want to find only the documents that contains only these two values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the values by appending the `secondValue` to the `authors` key. So the filter looks like `{ "authors" : "secondValue" }`.

So if you need the documents with array containing only two values including the order you need a filter like `{ "authors" : [ "firstValue", secondValue" ] }`

`Document authors = new Document("authors", Arrays.asList("firstValue", "secondValue"))`;